# UITapGestureRecognizer with pangesture

Tags: ios, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to use tap gesture recoznizer together with pan gesture, but i can make only one work. How can I use both on the one view?

Comment: Can you explain what do you want to do exactly

Comment: @JimmyJames I had already an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to your gesture recognizer to wo with other gesture recozniers. Please, use UIGestureRecognizer's delegate method shouldSimultaneouslyRecoznize.